# How to properly call a function with instance in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, oop, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send an email with SMTP in *Symfony 4* and I have the following function as per the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html).

```
public function send_smtp(\Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
        ->setFrom('send@example.com')
        ->setTo('MyEmail@gmail.com')
        ->setBody('test email content');
    $mailer->send($message);
}
```

However, I want to call this function from a different one like

```
$this->send_smtp();
```

But it complains about 'No parameters are passed' and

```
$this->send_smtp(\Swift_Mailer);
```

also gives the error message

> Undefined constant 'Swift_Mailer'

What can be the problem and how could it be solved?

Comment: If the parameter is the mailer, you need to call the function with a mailer parameter

Comment: You should inject swift_mailer service trough your class constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few solutions possible. You can add the parameter with typehinting in your action and then use it to call your function:

```
/**
 * @Route("/something")
 */
public function something(\Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $this->send_smtp($mailer);
}
```

or you can retrieve the service from the container in the send_smtp function:

```
public function send_smtp()
{
    $mailer = $this->get('mailer');

    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
        ->setFrom('send@example.com')
        ->setTo('MyEmail@gmail.com')
        ->setBody('test email content');

    $mailer->send($message);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create service e.g.

```
namespace App\Service\Mailer;

class Mailer
{
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public function send_smtp()
    {
        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
            ->setFrom('send@example.com')
            ->setTo('MyEmail@gmail.com')
            ->setBody('test email content');

        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }
}
```

And now you can inject this service wherever you want (e.g. to your Controller action or in another service) via `__construct`:

```
public function __construct(Mailer $mailer) 
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
}

public function someAction()
{
    $this->mailer->send_smtp()
}
```

Or you can inject it via method or via property. You can read more about injections here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html

P.S. I don't recommend you use container's method `get` because this method works only for public services, but in Symfony 4 services are private by default.